# tag system using PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create `tag system` for my article. now I have this `input` with `comma separated` :

```
trance, house, electronica, dubstep, club
```

now I need to `INSERT` this tags To `Tags` Table Like This:

```
ID        NAME             ArticleId
1         trance              10
2         house               10 
3         electronica         10
4         dubstep             10
5         garage              10
```

And How to `Fetch`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` , `UPDATE` This tags?!

Comment: Why wouldn't you keep the tags in one row instead of all tags seperate, the serach will be slower using LIKE but tags are searched less often than the general articles

Comment: Because if you need to search tags: `SELECT * FROM tags
WHERE name = 'trance';` faster and better `SELECT * FROM tags
WHERE tags LIKE '%transe%';`

Comment: @Kris Because of something called database normalization.

Comment: @Kristijan If you searched for `LIKE '%trance%'` and there was another tag called `trance-house` (lol) then it would pick up both despite them being separate. Also: How would you get a list of all the available tags without pulling all the records out, splitting the tags and then running some script on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `FETCH` using [Group Contact](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NAME) As tags FROM table_name WHERE ArticleId= 10;
```

will return like

```
trance, house, electronica, dubstep, club
```

for `DELETE` use simple [delete query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp)

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE name = 'trance'
```

Also for [UPDATE query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)  you can use like below

```
UPDATE table_name SET name = 'trance' WHERE ID = 1
```

**EDIT**

Use [INSERT query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

```
foreach($tag as $each_tag) {

    INSERT INTO table_name (ID, NAME, ArticleId)
    VALUES (1, '.$each_tag.', 10);
}
```

above is just skeleton map with your original code.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks How to `INSERT` Tags In `Tags` Table?! `Fetch`, `Delete` `Update` Worked Now.

Comment: `INSERT` Not Work!! we Need, first Separated tags and Then using `foreach` INSERT to table

Comment: pls see my loop code. will sure work for you.

Comment: `error`: invalid argument supplied for `foreach`. NOTE: before `foreach` we need to `implode()`, `explode` function for separate comma tags.

Comment: you can use $arr_tag = explode(",",$tags); and then make foreach from $arr_tag to insert from loop.